# Screen blank after uspend or automatic blank screen

Tags: suspend, display, 19.04

Using a laptop acer aspire 7 seriers with dual graphics card

always had issues with second monitor but this time the screen doesn't come back after blanking and Ctrl + F[1-7] doesn't help

Happened after upgrade to 19.04, using proprietary nvidia drivers

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for the issue, it had to do with the monitor, when I turned it off the problem would arise,

This article hinted me about it:
https://www.reddit.com/r/nvidia/comments/52cr0b/how_to_disable_the_video_card_from_going_to_sleep/

Comment: Something else that helped me as well was to disable composition from the Window manager Tweaks settings panel (using XFCE of course)